# Xgboost - Do we have to convert integers to factors if they are only 0 & 1

Tags: r, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

I have many columns in a dataframe that are flags "0" and "1". They belong to class "integer" when i import the dataframe.

0 denotes absence and 1 denotes presence in all columns.

Do i need to convert them to fators?[factors will make levels 1 & 2 while currently they are almost similar 0 & 1 albeit integers]

I plan to later use xgboost to build a predictive model.
Xgboost works only on numeric columns so if i convert the columns to factor's then i will need to one-hot encode them to convert them to numeric.

(Side question: Do we always need to drop one column if we do one hot encoding to remove collinearity?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Depends. Yes, just for better variable interpretation. No as for 0/1 variables integer and factors both are same.

If you ask my personal opinion then I am more towards YES; as you will more likely also be having some categorical variables which are either have string values or more than 2 levels or 2 integer levels other than 0 and 1. In all aforementioned cases 0/1 variables integer and factors both are NOT same. Only specific case of 0/1 binary levels; integer variable and factors are same. So you may want to bring consistency in your coding and even want to adopt this for 0/1 case as well.

To see yourself:

```
a <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,5)
c<-as.character(a)
b<-as.factor(c)
d<-as.integer(b)
```

Here I am just playing with `a` vector, which in end gives me:

```
> d
[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 3
```

So if you don't want to debug why values are changing in future then use `as.factor()` from starting.

Side Answer: Yes. Search for `model.matrix()` and `contrasts.arg` for getting this done in R.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `xgb.DMatrix` takes numeric values, where the data were integers.

To convert the data to numeric use

```
train[] <- lapply(train, as.numeric)
```

and then use

```
xgb.DMatrix(data=data.matrix(train))
```